# Remove hover effect on custom-styled MUI Switch component in React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm attempting to make a customized version of the MUI Switch component, but I'm having trouble with removing the on-hover effect when you hover over the switchbase (or at least what I believe is the switchbase) when the Switch is checked. On hover when checked, the switchbase takes on a bluish tint, which I believe is the default "on hover" styling for MUI buttons and anything with a ButtonBase. However, I can't figure out how to remove this. I've tried using a number of rules targeting the root, switchBase, thumb, and track components, and even added a checked style rule, but nothing seems to be working.

Below is the styling I've tried so far. A lot of the "on hover & checked" styling overlaps, but that's because I'm not sure where to put it and just put it in a bunch of different places to see if it would work (it hasn't thus far). In Chrome Dev Tools, I can see that when the Switch is checked, it gains the "Mui-checked" classes, however in the styles viewer/editor in the right I can't find where that on-hover color change comes from. It may also be related to the default color of the Switch being blue; I've done a lot of color changing and other additions that may not have actually succeeded in changing the underlying base color of the component.

```
const switchTheme = createTheme({
    components: {
        MuiSwitch: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "2.15em",
                    padding: "0px",
                    borderRadius: '0',
                    "&.Mui-checked": {
                        backgroundColor: "none",
                        color: "none"
                    }
                },
                switchBase: {
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "100%",
                    borderRadius: "0",
                    color: "white",
                    padding: "1px",
                    transform: "translateX(-23%)",
                    "&.Mui-checked": {
                        color: "none",
                        backgroundColor: "none",
                        transform: "translateX(23%)",
                        "&:hover": {
                            backgroundColor: "none",
                            color: "none",
                        }
                        // backgroundColor: "#212121",
                    }
                },
                // child of switchbase
                thumb: {
                    color: "white",
                    left: "0",
                    width: "50%",
                    height: "25px",
                    margin: "0.25em",
                    opacity: "0.1",
                    borderRadius: "5px",
                    "&:hover": {
                        color: "none",
                    },
                    '&.Mui-checked': {
                        color: "none",
                    }
                },
                track: {
                    width: "100%",
                    backgroundColor: "#212121",
                    padding: "0.5em",
                    borderRadius: "5px",
                    // Controls checked color for the track
                    ".Mui-checked.Mui-checked + &": {
                        backgroundColor: "#212121",
                    },
                },
                checked: {
                    "&.MuiSwitch-switchBase": {
                        color: "none",
                        backgroundColor: "none",
                    },
                    "&.MuiSwitch-root": {
                        color: "none",
                        backgroundColor: "none",
                    },
                }
            }
        }
}
```